# How can I read custom logs in OMS in docker containers?

Tags: docker, oms

Is there a way that I can get a custom log inside a docker container to be consumed by Azure's/Microsoft's OMS?

Installing the linux agent into every container seems like overkill and also against their container solution.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm using the Microsoft Docker container for oms, though I'll find out next month if each container costs $15 or just the hosts the container is on.